# How can I replace values in pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace doors count for every car model if it is NaN, using median for each model, but it doesnt work and i dont know why.

`for x in uniques['Марка']:
    models = data[data['Марка'] == x]['Модель'].unique()
    for y in models:
        data[(data['Модель'] == y) & (pd.isnull(data['Количество дверей']))]['Количество дверей'].replace(to_replace=np.nan, value=data[(data['Модель'] == y) & (pd.notnull(data['Количество дверей']))]['Количество дверей'].median(), inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

```
median = df['column_name']
df['column_name'].replace(np.nan, median, inplace=True)
```

This is one of the simpler approaches to replace missing values in a series.

Comment: check out df.fillna() as well.

Comment: Your code replace all values in column that are np, but I need to replace only values with same model